# What's the correct way for pronouncing "route"

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct pronunciation of the word “route”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-the-word-route)

I always thought that the word route should be pronounced as ru:t (my english dictionary also says that). But I hear people say it as raut. What's the correct way? Or both are correct?

Answer (score 2):

In US English, route is usually pronounced "root" in reference to a roadway, as in "Route 66." As a verb, e.g., "route the cables behind the monitor," you tend to hear "rowt." This is not a uniform distinction, nota bene.

Comment: What about the -ing form? What's the usual way pronunciation for routing? Is it different for "I'm routing" and "Routing Problem"?

Answer (score 1):

It is a pond difference - the UK pronunciation is ru:t, whereas the US pronunciation is raut.

However, it depends what you talk about. A router - as a part of a computer network - is pronouced with the ru:t start, whereas even in the UK, if it is a DIY power tool, it is pronounced raut.

Comment: Bit of a red herring that. What the power tool does is rout (pronounced raut everywhere); what the electronic gizmo does is route (something).

Comment: In the U.S., even people who pronounce the highway [ru:t] generally pronounce the piece of the computer network [rautɚ].